# How to create folder in Alfresco by RESTful API

Tags: alfresco

I am using [Freshdocs](https://github.com/freshdocs/cmsandroid) for Android

I can login to the Alfresco server using this API call:

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/login?u={username}&pw={password?}
```

But how do I create a new folder in Alfresco?

Comment: What does it have to do with android? Please remove the tag.

Comment: hi, i making a android application to connect to Afresco

Comment: This doesn't seem to matter here if you're only interested in finding out something about alfresco's rest api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main options, but it'll depend on what else you want to do, and what version of Alfresco you're running.

Assuming you want to keep things very simple, and you just want to create one folder, and you're using Alfresco 4.1 or later, then you can use the `org.alfresco.repository.node.folder.post` webscript. For this, simply post JSON like either

```
 { "name": "NewNodeName" }
```

or

```
{  
   "name": "NewNodeName",
   "title": "New Node Title",
   "description": "A shiny new node",
   "type": "cm:folder"
}
```

To the API, which takes a URL like `/api/site/folder/{site}/{container}/{path}`

Alternately, if you want to do a number of different file and folder operations (eg navigate the folder structure, create a folder, upload a file to it etc), then you should instead use [CMIS](http://cmis.alfresco.com/). [Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/) is a great library to use for CMIS, and it even has an Android client! The docs for the android client are still being written thought (the Android port was only just added), so you might need to ask on the [mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/chemistry-dev/) if you don't have time to wait for the docs.

Comment: I am using Freshdocs: https://github.com/freshdocs/cmsandroid. What kind of api which Freshdocs use?

Comment: That looks to be a CMIS client too

Comment: But they dont use any library

Comment: The CMIS client is inline in the source tree

Comment: but i see they use some restful API : http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference . Are there any diffirent between CMIS client and Restful

Comment: I'd suggest you go and start reading up on what CMIS is.... It can work via RESTful ATOM, or WebServices, or with CMIS 1.1 with RESTful JSON.

Comment: hi, can CMIS use this api: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference

Comment: It's an alternative, which is more generic (works across different repos). You really ought to go and read up on CMIS....

Answer (score 2):

To create a folder through api you can use the following queries:

a) To create defined type folder using  full path to parent folder

```
       url: "/../alfresco/service/api/site/folder/" + siteName + "/documentLibrary/" + parentFolderPath
       method: "POST"
       json: {
           name: name
           type: folderType
       }
```

siteName - website name created in Alfresco;

parentFolderPath - path to parent folder;

name -folder name;

type - folder type.

Example:

```
     url: "/../alfresco/service/api/site/folder/example/documentLibrary/books"
       method: "POST"
       json: {
           name: "Pushkin"
           type: "cm:folder"
       }
```

After making the request "Pushkin" folder is created. This folder is situated in “books” folder of documents library on the "example" website.

b) To create folder by nodeRef

nodeRef  is an object id in Alfresco. Each object has its own nodeRef. This request creates new object inside given object of folder type.

```
       xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/"
    xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">' +
           '<title>' + folderName + '</title>' +
           '<summary>' + folderName + '</summary>' +
           '<cmisra:object>' +
           '<cmis:properties>' +
           '<cmis:propertyId
    propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">' +
           '<cmis:value>' + folderType + '</cmis:value>' +
           '</cmis:propertyId>' +
           '</cmis:properties>' +
           '</cmisra:object>' +
           '</entry>';
       url: "/../alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/" +
    nodeRef + "/children"
       method: "POST"
       headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml;type=entry"
       },
       xml: xml
```

folderName - folder name;

folderType -  folder type;

nodeRef - folder id in Alfresco.

Example:

```
       nodeRef = b544cd67-e839-4c60-a616-9605fa2affb7;
       xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
           '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/"
    xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">' +
           '<title>Example of creating a folder</title>' +
           '<summary>Example of creating a folder</summary>' +
           '<cmisra:object>' +
           '<cmis:properties>' +
           '<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">' +
           '<cmis:value>cm:folder</cmis:value>' +
           '</cmis:propertyId>' +
           '</cmis:properties>' +
           '</cmisra:object>' +
           '</entry>';
       url: "/../alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/" + nodeRef + "/children"
       method: "POST"
       headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/atom+xml;type=entry"
        },
       xml: xml
```

Other services and their description you can find here:

http://jazzteam.org/en/technical-articles/list-of-alfresco-services/

Comment: can you please let me know what is the complete url / curl  for  part a? I have a hard time figuring out the URL and its parameters. where is the prefix for the url is it supposed to be http://127.0.0.1:8080/../alfresco/service/api/site/folder/example/documentLibrary/books if I have it installed my local machine? Please let me know thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use 
`POST /alfresco/service/api/path/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}/children`

Read the docs for detailed information:

http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Create_folder_or_document_.28createDocument.2C_createFolder.29

Comment: i saw this api before, but i dont know what is : {store_type},{store_id},{id}

Comment: It's the different parts of the NodeRef of the parent node you want to create the child in