# How to bulk import documents with custom metadata from csv to Alfresco repo?

Tags: csv, alfresco-share, bulk-load

I have an excel file (or csv), that holds a list of documents with their properties and absolute paths in local hard drive.
Now that we are going to use Alfresco (v5.0.d) as DMS, I have already created a custom aspect which reflect the csv fields and I'm looking for a better approach to import all document from the csv file into Alfresco repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply write java application to parse your csv and upload files, file by file using the RESTful api and do not forget to replicate the folder tree in your alfresco repo (as it is not recommended to have more than 1000 folders/documents on the same level in the hierarchy since it would require some tweaking in a few non trivial usecases).

To create the folder, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11711039/2307988).

To actually upload the files, refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575960/saving-file-in-alfresco-with-version-and-download-the-latest-version/34587787#34587787).