# Creating a sub folder node in Alfresco Community Edition v5.0.0

Tags: php, rest, laravel, alfresco

I've got a Laravel project whereby I'm creating files on the server, and then uploading a folder and all of its contents to an Alfresco site, using the RESTful services.

What I've done so far:

- Login is working
- Uploading a file into a node with the nodeId

What I'm struggling with:

How can I create a folder under the site, knowing the root nodeId/nodeRef, using the RESTful services and not the CMIS services? Is there an easier way to achieve this?

I've tried using the instructions below, as well as searched this on Stackoverflow before, trying the suggestions others have posted, but to no avail (I get a 404 or 500 response even though the nodeId I pass is valid)

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/RESTful-NodeFolderPost.html

I also find the Community documentation to be quite limiting and brief which doesn't help very much.

Any help or guidance would be immensely appreciated! :)

**Edit:**

I've read over this post (and many others):
[How to create folder in Alfresco by RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710908/how-to-create-folder-in-alfresco-by-restful-api)

I have a few functions already built which are working already using the RESTful services, the last one I need to do is creating a folder node. I don't mind using the CMIS solution, but I would prefer to keep that as my last resort, because the subsystem I've build is micro, and the importing and using another library reduces the priority of this solution.

**Put plainly**: Is there not a way to POST a JSON structure to a URL of the Alfresco instance to create a folder node under my site's document library?

I've tried these prescribed ways:

```
POST /alfresco/service/api/node/folder/{store_type}/{store_id}/{id}
POST /alfresco/service/api/site/folder/{site}/{container}/{path}
POST /alfresco/service/api/site/folder/{site}/{container}
```

The first one creates a node which isn't accessible via the document library, and the other two return 404/500 responses

Comment: Why do you want to avoid CMIS? It uses a RESTful API behind the scenes.

Comment: The reason for avoiding the CMIS solution is generating and sifting through the Atom XML. Unless you can suggest an easy way to do that in a Laravel/PHP, I had to spend quite a bit of time traversing a the response structure of the Atom feed XML to achieve a simple task of uploading a file

Comment: Not sure if this is going to help, but, the [Apache OpenCMIS](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html) library provides an implementation for PHP clients (and it also supports bindings for Web Services and Atom Publishing protocol). I used the Java implementation and creating folders was just one line of code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'd like to use that as a last resort, I feel that it's almost a little unnecessary to use an entire library to parse 3 different type of requests in the small integration I'm doing (if that makes sense). It's a small sub system to create a folder note under the site, as well as upload numerous files. Surely there must be a way to create a folder under the site's root node via the RESTful services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've just found a StackOverflow answer to my own question - I hope anyone who's looking for a solution to this problem finds this and it saves them a couple days of dev time:

You can create a node in your documentLibrary root, as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24010096/3951987

Request:

```
URL: {alfresco_server}/alfresco/service/api/site/folder/{site_name}/documentLibrary/
Body: 
{
"name" : /*folder_name*/,
"title": /*folder_title*/,
"description" : /*folder_description*/,
"type" : "cm:folder"
}
```

Param descriptions:

- alfresco_server: The domain where your Alfresco instance resides
- site_name: The name of the site you'd like to access in your Alfresco instance
- folder_name: (Required) The name of your folder.
- folder_title: (Optional) The title of your folder. This is the human readable version of the folder, where spaces are allowed.
- folder_description: (Optional) A description of this node/folder.

You can append a folder_name to the URL after '.../documentLibrary/' to create sub directories.

Thanks to all who gave suggestions for solutions here :)